# What is the efficient way to save a dataframe into a Hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

We are migrating from Greenplum to HDFS.
Data comes from source tables to Greenplum thru huge ETL and from Greenplum, we are just dumping the data into HDFS using Spark.
So I am trying to read a GP table and load it into Hive tables on HDFS using Spark.

I have a dataframe read from a GP table as below:

```
  val yearDF    = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                            .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2017")
                            .option("user", devUserName)
                            .option("password", devPassword)
                            .option("numPartitions",10)
                            .load()
```

There are different options to save a dataframe into a Hive table.

First Method:

```
yearDf.write().mode("overwrite").partitionBy("source_system_name","period_year","period_num").saveAsTable("schemaName.tableName");
```

Second Method:

```
 myDf.createOrReplaceTempView("yearData");
 spark.sql("insert into schema.table partition("source_system_name","period_year","period_num") select * from yearData");
```

What are the pros and cons of the above mentioned ways ?
We have huge tables in production which usually take lot of time to load the data into Hive. Could anyone let me know which is the efficient and recommended way to save data from a dataframe to Hive table ?

Comment: My 2 cents: be careful with vocabulary -- HDFS is not a database, Hive is not something you store data into...

Comment: "Efficiency" has a lot to do with how you expect to **use** that data after load. Which file format do you consider -- ORC, Parquet, AVRO, CSV? With compression, and which kind? Partitioned, and how? ...And also, how do you expect to **update** the data, without support of Update/Delete operations?

Comment: About your specific (but out of context) question : both ways should have the same "efficiency" but SQL _Insert_ should provide better binary compatibility with Hive.

Comment: file format: ORC, compression: ZLIB, partition columns: we have three columns source_system_name, period_year, period_num, dynamically partitioned.
Regarding the update/deletes, I haven't written the code yet. First I am trying to load data into HDFS. I have to come up with code to send the incremental data once this phase is over.

Comment: I guess you already looked carefully at the refactoring of ORC library in Spark 2.3 (c/o HortonWorks) https://dataworkssummit.com/berlin-2018/session/orc-improvement-in-apache-spark-2-3/ especially the part about _... switching between “native” and “hive” ORC file formats..._

Comment: Your code snippet about reading from JDBC is missing some mandatory options (the tricky part, in fact) about how to split records into 10 partitions -- read in parallel from 10 executors running 10 concurrent DB sessions -- without too much skew...

Comment: BTW, do you really have enough RAM to store the whole table in memory?? With `spark.rdd.compress=true` and LZ4 you might have a x2 increase in capacity (if you are lucky), but run your stress tests carefully...

Comment: Okay. I will definitely check all the options you mentioned above.

Comment: I do agree with Samson.. use partitioncol ,lower bound and uperbound and numpartitions while making jdbc connection to your source. This was you can achieve more parallelism.